# Combining semi transparency of background image with keyframe animation

Tags: css, background, transparency

I would like to add a continuous fading effect in the background image of my wrapper. I know you can use keyframe animation to make a background image move arround, however, i was wondering if there is a fade effect possible using this technique.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/

For example:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fontbulger {
0% {
    font-size: 10px;
}
30% {
    font-size: 15px;
}
100% {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Would be in my perfect situation something like...

```
@-webkit-keyframes fontbulger {
0% {
    background: url(image.png, 1);
}
30% {
    background: url(image.png, 0.5);
}
100% {
    background: url(image.png, 1);
}
```

...for which 0.5 would be a visibility of 50%. Ofcourse, this suggestion does not work. Any way to accomplish this? I know you can apply transparency to [RGB value's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8740149/1122073), but I would like to apply it to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way currently to directly affect the opacity of the background image as you seek. Two possible workarounds are:

### 1. Pure CSS3 way (not well supported yet)

Using a pseudo-element to supply the `background-image` allowed `opacity` to be used and keep the whole thing as pure css, *but it did not work on `webkit`* (which apparently does not support animation on pseudo-elements), only on the `moz` extension (I could not test IE10... feedback on that would be helpful). Compare Firefox with Chrome for [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VdAu/2/), which used this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bkgAnimate">Foreground text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bkgAnimate {
    width: 300px; /*only for demo*/
    height: 200px; /*only for demo*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* make a local stacking context */
}

.bkgAnimate:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(src="your/image/path/file.png") no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;  
    -webkit-animation: fontbulger  3s infinite;
    -moz-animation:    fontbulger  3s infinite;
    -ms-animation:     fontbulger  3s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fontbulger {
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
    30%  { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fontbulger  {
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
    30%  { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fontbulger  {
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
    30%  { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

### 2. Cluttered HMTL solution (more cross browser friendly)

Changing to put an actual `img` tag in as the background seemed to be the only way to get `webkit` to behave, as [this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/2VdAu/7/). But that may not be desirable for you. Code similar to above except:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bkgAnimate">Foreground text 
  <img class="bkg" src="your/image/path/file.png"/>
</div>
```

**CSS change from above**

Change the `:after` selector to `.bkgAnimate .bkg` and remove the `content` and `background` property from that code.