# How properly set background opacity in one line in style of body?

Tags: html, css

How properly set background opacity with next:

```
<body style="background-image: url(images/background.jpg); background-color: white;
 background-position: center center; background-size: 100%; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat">
```

I try with:

```
background-opacity: 0.5;
```

But fail.

It should be something like:

```
background-image: url(images/background.jpg) opacity: 0.5;
```

Even,

```
opacity: .4;
```

Doesn't affect on image, but affect on the text and whole of body.

Solutions with div doesn't accepted.

My web page: http://shell.bshellz.net/~panzerdivision/

Browsers: firefox & chrome

Answer (score 2):

Using `opacity` property, changes the opacity of the element itself.

To have a transparent `background-color` you could use `rgba()` as background color instead:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
```

Or in short-hand:

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) url(path/to/transparent/background.png) center center no-repeat;
```

**But** If you need to have a transparent background image, the image **should** be transparent itself.

By the way, [here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692020/1725764) to give opacity to `background-image` but I'm not sure whether or not is could be useful in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, check my page, i use your example code.

Comment: @innocent-world As I mentioned *the image should be transparent itself*, but take a look at the link in the answer, It might be helpful.

Comment: This is exist in my question "Solutions with div doesn't accepted.", i know how to make it with div. But looks like body's style is powerful and should keep this option.

Comment: @innocent-world You can also use `::before` pseudo-element to implement that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the opacity of the entire background of an element using CSS.

- You can set the opacity of an entire element (with the `opacity` property).
- You can set the opacity of a background colour (with an `rgba` colour: `background-color: rgba(50%, 50%, 50%, 0.5);`)

If you want a translucent background image, you have to encode the opacity in the image itself (use the PNG or WebP image formats, which support this).

Comment: Your answer: with css Only colour can be changed? ):

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and adjust the width as you want

```
<p><img style="opacity:0.9;" src="C:\Users\Desktop\images.jpg" width="300" height="231" alt="Image" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://css-tricks.com/maybe-there-kinda-is-background-opacity/

```
.el {
  background-image: -webkit-cross-fade(
    url(image.jpg),
    url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7),
    50%
  );
```

By fading image with a transparent base64 url encoded gif you can get to where you wanted so many years ago. :)

Does not currently work on Firefox. :(

Answer (score 0):

To set the background opacity of the body element in one line using inline styles, you can use the **rgba()** CSS function to specify the background color with an alpha value (opacity). The **rgba()** function takes four parameters: red, green, blue, and alpha, where alpha specifies the opacity level from 0 (fully transparent) to 1 (fully opaque).

Here's how you can set the background opacity of the body element in one line:

```
<body style="background-image: url(images/background.jpg); background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); background-position: center center; background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat">
```

In this example, the **rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)** value for **background-color** sets the background color to white with 50% opacity, giving a semi-transparent effect.

Adjust the last parameter **(0.5 in this example)** as needed to control the opacity level. Use 0 for fully transparent and 1 for fully opaque, and any value in between for various levels of opacity.